# Flutter - ListView.Builder with two direction scroll and unknown children size

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm building a data list like this

```
List<String> list=[.....];  //a lot of data
ListView.builder(
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    controller: scrollController,
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) => 
        ListTile(title: Text(list[i])))
```

It can scroll on vertical now but some long data will overflow on the right,so I want to add a horizontal scroll outside.

I tried many ways but it always return error such as "'constraints.hasBoundedWidth': is not true."

Code like this works fine but I have to set a width in Container first :

```
ListView(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    children: [
        Container(
            width: 2000,    //will return error if not set a value
            child: ListView.builder(.....)
                 )])
```

Is there any way to add a horizontal scroll outside with unknown child width?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong in vertical list. I have run code in android studio as well.
no need to use Listview in the inner of another list view. you can wrap your title with Expanded widget, if your list title overflow on right side of screen.

```
return ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        itemCount:100,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) =>
            ListTile(title: Text("{$i ===}babul dshdshfdsh dfhdhfdh hbfdshhds hdfhdsvhfdsv hdsvd hdsfhdshv dhfbhdsb hdsghshdsg hdvshvv jdsfjfdbvjfdnfjbfjbfhbfbf fhbfdhbfdhbf")));
  }
```

[image]

Comment: But I want those text not changing line and can scroll horizontal ....

Answer (score 0):

Below code will serve your purpose. Happy coding...

```
 return Container(
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount:10,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) =>
               SingleChildScrollView(
                 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: new Text(
                  "Description that is too long in text format(Here Data is coming from API Description that is too long in text format)",
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black87,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
        ),);
```

Comment: It look like will let each child scroll themselves. Is it possible to scroll entire ListView.builder ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. just put ListView.builder,  ScrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

Comment: So is it possible to add horizontal scroll "outside" the vertical ListView.builder to make it scroll entire data list?